# Issue while retrieving the data from elastic using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve the data from elastic DB by using multiple conditions like, "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date" in between 24hrs and "platform" which belongs to COSMOS. I am using the below code for these conditions

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {
                        "platform": "COSMOS"
                    }}],
            "filter": [
                {"range": {
                        "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date": {
                            "gte": "2022-05-31 00:00:00",
                            "lt": "2022-05-31 23:59:59"
                        }}}]}}}
```

The above code is working fine when I have used it in Postman.(satisfying both "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date" and "platform" conditions)

**But if I am trying to implement the same conditions in C# only one condition is satisfying i.e.; "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date" in between 24hrs rest condition "platform" = COSMOS is not working.... Instead of that my C# code is retrieving all Platforms data in between 24hrs**

Below is my c# code. In **string json** I am passing these conditions.

```
        public static string COSMOS(string getAPiurl, string ApiUserId, string ApiPassword)
        {
            string url = getAPiurl;
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            webrequest.Method = "POST";
            webrequest.ContentType = "application/JSON";
            webrequest.Accept = "application/JSON";

            String username = ApiUserId;
            String password = ApiPassword;
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

            webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);


            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webrequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"from\": 0,\"size\": 10000,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"should\":[{\"match\":{\"platform\":{\"query\":\"COSMOS\"}}}],\"filter\":[{\"range\":{\"cu_ticketLastUpdated_date\":{\"gte\":\"2022-05-31 00:00:00\",\"lt\":\"2022-05-31 23:59:59\"}}}]}}}";
                
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                httpResponse.Close();
                //MessageBox.Show(result);
                return result;

            }


        }
```

I am trying multiple ways to fix it. But I am unable to fix this issue. Can any one help me with the solution.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the offical nugget package to interact with Elasticsearch ? I feel you should use `must` instead of `should`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

You are not doing the same query in `postman` and in `c#`.
In postman you use a `must` clause while in the `c#` you use `should`.

## To Fix

```cs
public static string COSMOS(string getAPiurl, string ApiUserId, string ApiPassword)
{
    string url = getAPiurl;
    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    webrequest.Method = "POST";
    webrequest.ContentType = "application/JSON";
    webrequest.Accept = "application/JSON";

    String username = ApiUserId;
    String password = ApiPassword;
    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

    webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);


    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webrequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"from\": 0,\"size\": 10000,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"platform\":{\"query\":\"COSMOS\"}}}],\"filter\":[{\"range\":{\"cu_ticketLastUpdated_date\":{\"gte\":\"2022-05-31 00:00:00\",\"lt\":\"2022-05-31 23:59:59\"}}}]}}}";
        
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        httpResponse.Close();
        //MessageBox.Show(result);
        return result;

    }


}
```